# How to show animation in verifone vx520?

Tags: point-of-sale, verifone

I want to show animation in verifone vx520. Here is my code but it doesn't show anything on the screen. How should I my initialize my bitmapped file to this function?
How can I use and animate `animationbmp`?

```
#define RGB2PIXEL565(r,g,b)            \
         ((((r) & 0xf8) << 8) | (((g) & 0xfc) << 3) | (((b) & 0xf8) >> 3))
void animate(void) {
char animationbmp[]="move.bmp"
    int con;
short * frameBuffer;
         frameBuffer=(short*)malloc(8); 
         con = open (DEV_CONSOLE, 0);
         frameBuffer[0]= RGB2PIXEL565 (0xFF,  0,  0 ); // red
         frameBuffer[1]= RGB2PIXEL565 (0,   0xFF, 0 ); // green
         frameBuffer[2]= RGB2PIXEL565 (0,   0,  0xFF); // blue
         frameBuffer[3]= RGB2PIXEL565 (0xFF, 0, 0xFF); // purple

         set_display_coordinate_mode (PIXEL_MODE);
         display_frame_buffer(0,0,4,1,frameBuffer);
         display_frame_buffer(1,2,2,2,frameBuffer);
         display_frame_buffer(5,1,1,4,frameBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Does your 520 have a color display?

Comment: @PhatWrat: No. I just write the example in document in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if Verifone Vx520 can show animation files, but the easiest way to display animation is to periodically change pictures. Here are an example of code:

```
void animation(char *file1, char *file2, int x, int y){
    set_display_coordinate_mode(PIXEL_MODE);
    put_BMP_at(x,y, (char *)file1);    //Draw image on a display starting from pos (x;y)
    SVC_WAIT(some_pause_in_msec);    //system function like "sleep"
    put_BMP_at(x,y, (char *)file2);    //Draw image on a display
    SVC_WAIT(some_pause_in_msec);    
    set_display_coordinate_mode(CHARACTER_MODE);    //Back to text display mode (optional)
}
```

About how to work with image files (".BMP") you can read [here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/274353975/DOC00301-Verix-EVo-Volume-I-Operating-System-Programmers-Manual).
Your files must be black-white ".bmp" files for Vx520.

Comment: "I don't know exactly" means that i never saw this in documentation.